# Doubt in Location Lemma in Greens Relation Abstract Algebra!

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid, greens-relations

I am unable to prove one part of rectangular lemma in green's relations.
Let $S^1$ be a monoid. Then I need to prove that $m.m' \in D(m) \iff m.m'\in R(m) \cap L(m')$. How should I go about proving this?
$R(m)$ is Right equivalence classes of m. 
$L(m')$ is Left equivalence classes of m'. 
$D(m)$ is the equivalence class of m, defined by relation $D=L\circ R=R\circ L$.
I know that $x\in R(m) \iff \exists a,b:xa=m$ and $x=mb$. Symmetrically for $L(m')$. 
Also, $D=L\circ R=R\circ L$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: What does it mean that $mm'\in D$? If $D$ is a relation, then its elements are pairs.

Comment: Oops! $mm' \in D$ meant that $mm'$ is in the equivalence class of $m$ (which is also the same as equivalence class of $m'$). Question edited!

Comment: Your notation is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in arbitrary monoids. For instance, it is not true in the [bicyclic monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicyclic_semigroup).

The *bicyclic monoid* is the monoid with presentation $\langle \{a, b\} \mid ab = 1 \rangle$. I let you verify that every element of the bicyclic monoid can be written uniquely in the form $b^ma^n$, where $m, n \geq 0$. The product of such words is given by
$$
(b^ma^n)(b^pa^q) = b^ra^s
$$ where $r = m - n + \max(n,p) = m + p - \min(n,p)$ and $s = q - p + \max(n,p) = n + q - \min(n,p)$.
The idempotents are the elements of the form $b^na^n$, with $n \geqslant
0$. It contains a single $\cal D$-class and $\cal D = \cal J$. Its egg-box picture is represented below:

$\hskip 100pt$[image]

Let $R(x)$, $L(x)$ and $D(x)$ be the $\cal R$-class, the $\cal L$-class and the $\cal D$-class of an element $x$. Then $b, ba \in D(b)$.  It is also true that $bba \in L(ba)$. However, $bba \notin R(b)$.